# Stop Motion Animation CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation

Я создаю анимацию  движения бегущей кошки.
 У меня уже есть все слайды. Но, похоже, это не работает должным образом.

```css
div {
  animation: run 1s steps(10) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: run 1s steps(10) infinite;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl4Tr.png) 0 0; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

@keyframes run {  
  0% {background-position: 100% 0; } 
  100% {background-position: 100% -2591px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes run {  
  0% {background-position: 100% 0; } 
  100% {background-position: 100% -2591px; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Перевод вопроса: [Stop Motion Animation CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27835008/7394871) @imbaktu

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27835008/7394871

Comment: Это простой перевод вопроса? Зачем?

Comment: @Erm ключевое слово здесь - ассоциация Посмотрите на Мете зачем это делается. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Теперь понятно, спасибо)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На самом деле у вас 13 слайдов.

Поэтому установите тринадцать шагов  `steps(13)`

```css
div {
  animation: run 1s steps(13) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: run 1s steps(13) infinite;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl4Tr.png) 0 0; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

@keyframes run {  
  0% {background-position: 100% 0; } 
  100% {background-position: 100% -2591px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes run {  
  0% {background-position: 100% 0; } 
  100% {background-position: 100% -2591px; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[перевод ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27835058/7394871) @The Pragmatick

Примечание переводчика:
Мне очень понравилось данное решение - минимальное количество кода и эффектно выглядит. Тут добавить еще бы параллакс бэкграунда.

Я  слежу за другими решениями подобных задач. Приведу несколько примеров:

**Примеры анимации персонажей**

1. [Идущий человек на фоне города](https://codepen.io/sdras/pen/azEBEZ)
2. [Шериф](https://codepen.io/cobra_winfrey/pen/NgEzZP)
3. [Бегущий человек](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/gpWLbW)
4. [Мультяшный герой](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/yNqNyq)
5. [Собака](https://codepen.io/marknelson/pen/KwJmjj)
6. [Бегущий человек, есть возможность менять предметы в его руке](http://codepen.io/CyrilLevallois/pen/JbrfI)
7. [Бегущая лошадка](https://codepen.io/CyrilLevallois/pen/Dtfhd)
8. [Бегущий волк](https://codepen.io/rafszul/pen/bNERPL)
9. [Прогулка скелета](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/EKqXQW) made by hand! @HamSter
10. [Анимация  с использованием svg совместно с параллаксом фона](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/842172/28748)
11. [Анимация персонажа прыгающей девочки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/841252/28748)
12. [Анимация персонажа с использованием svg совместно с параллаксом фона](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/842171/28748)
13. [Анимация пешеходных и других маршрутов на растровой карте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/870989/28748)

Comment: и стоило это переводить?)) больше похоже "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой"

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Мне очень понравилась тема Я довольно плотно думал, как её решить. Вот мои попытки https://svg-art.ru/files/animation/viewBox-translate/viewBox-translate2.html а тут всё просто и эффектно решается, так что сорри