# Анимация персонажа прыгающей девочки

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

На просторах интернета нашел гифку  прыгающей девочки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возник вопрос,- как реализовать эту анимацию с помощью CSS или SVG?

Понятно, что нужно нарисовать спрайт, состоящий из отдельных кадров и заставить их поочередно перемещаться в окне равным по ширине одному кадру.

Answer (score 20):

- Рисуем или находим готовый спрайт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Ширина спрайта - `640px` Ширина одного кадра будет задана - `160px`
- Спрайт добавляется в качестве фона и будет дискретно, по кадру
  перемещаться в окне равному по ширине и высоте одному кадру: `width: 160px;` и    `height: 276px;`
- команда анимации  перемещения: `animation: run 0.5s steps(4) infinite;`
- Осталось подобрать подходящий музыкальный фрагмент: **"Boney M -  Happy
  Song"**

**Update 18.03.2019 г.**

Chrome запретил автоматический запуск `mp3` поэтому добавил аудиоплейер.

Добавлена фоновая картинка дворика.

**Update 24.09.2020 г.**

1. Доработан спрайт png Фон стал прозрачный
2. Подарена девочке скакалка
3. Запуск муз. трека - кнопка `Play`

**Лучше смотреть в полноэкранном режиме**

```css
.house { 
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f4Hg.jpg);
background-size:cover;

}
.girl {
  animation: run 0.5s steps(4) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: run 0.5s steps(4) infinite;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D4RP.png) 0 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position:absolute ;
  bottom:0%;
  right:50%;
  
  width: 160px;
  height: 276px;
  
}

@keyframes run {
  from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -612px;
  }
}

.play-audio {
width:10%;
height:10%;
position:absolute;
bottom:5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="house">
<div class="girl"> </div>
<div class="play-audio">
  <svg class="svg1"  viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <g id="btn" onclick='play()' >
   <rect  x="5" y="105" rx="15"  id="rec1" width="150px" height="60px" fill="#4975B2" />
    <text x="35" y="150" font-size="48"  fill="white" pointer-events="none"> Play </text>
 </g>       
</svg>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var Hsong = new Audio();
Hsong.src = 'https://svg-art.ru/files/Hsong.mp3';

function play() {
  Hsong.play();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Прикольная девочка))))

Answer (score 9):

Ответ разумеется не по теме, но тут так же анимация но на чистом css - очень эффектно выглядит

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
  perspective: 500px;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.paper_man_wrapper {
  -webkit-animation: cameraY 7000ms linear infinite;
  animation: cameraY 7000ms linear infinite;
}

.paper_man {
  top: -100px;
  left: -50px;
  -webkit-animation: cameraX 5000ms ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: cameraX 5000ms ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.paper_man .part {
  background: black;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.paper_man .part::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #646464;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.paper_man_body {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-20deg);
  transform: rotateX(-20deg);
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: shake4 2000ms -100ms ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: shake4 2000ms -100ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

.paper_man_head {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  top: -40px;
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-10deg);
  transform: rotateX(-10deg);
  -webkit-animation: shake4 1000ms -800ms ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: shake4 1000ms -800ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

.paper_man_arm.left {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  right: 0px;
  -webkit-animation: shake1 1000ms -400ms ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: shake1 1000ms -400ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

.paper_man_arm.right {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  left: -20px;
  -webkit-animation: shake1 1000ms -900ms ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: shake1 1000ms -900ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

.paper_man_arm_1 {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
}

.paper_man_arm_2 {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  bottom: -50px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
}

.left .paper_man_arm_2 {
  -webkit-animation: shake3 1000ms -800ms ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: shake3 1000ms -800ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

.right .paper_man_arm_2 {
  -webkit-animation: shake3 1000ms -300ms ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: shake3 1000ms -300ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

.paper_man_arm_hand {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  bottom: -15px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
}

.left .paper_man_arm_hand {
  -webkit-animation: shake3 1000ms -200ms ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: shake3 1000ms -200ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

.right .paper_man_arm_hand {
  -webkit-animation: shake3 1000ms -700ms ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: shake3 1000ms -700ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

.paper_man_leg {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  top: 100px;
}

.paper_man_leg.left {
  right: 30px;
  -webkit-animation: shake1 1000ms ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: shake1 1000ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

.paper_man_leg.right {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: shake1 1000ms -500ms ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: shake1 1000ms -500ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

.paper_man_leg_1 {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
}

.paper_man_leg_2 {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  bottom: -40px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 40px;
}

.left .paper_man_leg_2 {
  -webkit-animation: shake2 1000ms -600ms ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: shake2 1000ms -600ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

.right .paper_man_leg_2 {
  -webkit-animation: shake2 1000ms -100ms ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: shake2 1000ms -100ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

.paper_man_leg_foot {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
}

.left .paper_man_leg_foot {
  -webkit-animation: shake3 1000ms -400ms ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: shake3 1000ms -400ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

.right .paper_man_leg_foot {
  -webkit-animation: shake3 1000ms -900ms ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: shake3 1000ms -900ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(80deg);
    transform: rotateX(80deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-80deg);
    transform: rotateX(-80deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(80deg);
    transform: rotateX(80deg);
  }
}

@keyframes shake1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(80deg);
    transform: rotateX(80deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-80deg);
    transform: rotateX(-80deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(80deg);
    transform: rotateX(80deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-100deg);
    transform: rotateX(-100deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes shake2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-100deg);
    transform: rotateX(-100deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(10deg);
    transform: rotateX(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(120deg);
    transform: rotateX(120deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(10deg);
    transform: rotateX(10deg);
  }
}

@keyframes shake3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(10deg);
    transform: rotateX(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(120deg);
    transform: rotateX(120deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(10deg);
    transform: rotateX(10deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake4 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg);
    transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-10deg);
    transform: rotateX(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg);
    transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  }
}

@keyframes shake4 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg);
    transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-10deg);
    transform: rotateX(-10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg);
    transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cameraY {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes cameraY {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cameraX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-50deg);
    transform: rotateX(-50deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(50deg);
    transform: rotateX(50deg);
  }
}

@keyframes cameraX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-50deg);
    transform: rotateX(-50deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(50deg);
    transform: rotateX(50deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="paper_man_wrapper">
    <div class="paper_man">
      <div class="paper_man_body part">
        <div class="paper_man_head part"></div>
        <div class="paper_man_arm left">
          <div class="paper_man_arm_1 part">
            <div class="paper_man_arm_2 part">
              <div class="paper_man_arm_hand part"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="paper_man_arm right">
          <div class="paper_man_arm_1 part">
            <div class="paper_man_arm_2 part">
              <div class="paper_man_arm_hand part"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="paper_man_leg left">
          <div class="paper_man_leg_1 part">
            <div class="paper_man_leg_2 part">
              <div class="paper_man_leg_foot part"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="paper_man_leg right">
          <div class="paper_man_leg_1 part">
            <div class="paper_man_leg_2 part">
              <div class="paper_man_leg_foot part"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Источник: [Yusuke Nakaya](https://codepen.io/YusukeNakaya/pen/vdjpyr)

Comment: Хороший пример, очень оригинальный, как впрочем и всё остальное у этого японца (+)

Comment: оо...я этот пример с какого то сайта скомуниздил но не с codepen

Comment: Ответ не отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: @Ver Nick вы не обратили внимание, что вопрос и ответ на него от одного человека. Это действие целиком поддерживается администрацией сайта - делится своими знаниями в форме вопрос - ответ. Почему вы оценили это отрицательно, не понятно. Плохое настроение?

Comment: Ладно, я понял :)