# Как подключить mp3 на стороннем ресурсе

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть топик на нашем сайте, в котом реализована анимация с автоматическим запуском воспроизведением файла `*.mp3`:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/841252/28748

Команда автоматического воспроизведения `mp3`

```
<audio src="https://svg-art.ru/files/Hsong.mp3" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>
```

Это работает и на локальном ПК и в сниппете `stackoferflow` во всех современных браузерах.

На [codepen](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/pen/YvQyXy) воспроизведение музыки в `Chrome` не работает.
 Firefox - воспроизводится нормально.

Посоветуйте, какая команда HTML или код JS может решить эту задачу.

Comment: Все работает...

Comment: @ Duoxx сейчас уточню вопрос: FF - работает, Chrome - нет

Comment: Теперь понятно, я просто хромом не пользуюсь.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: Новая политика хрома

Comment: Ну я в SVG не профи, мне так кажется что там и своя магия есть. Даже через js не получается, программный плей `audio.play()` тоже не работает. Магия да и только.