# SVG Покадровая анимация svg картинок

Tags: css, svg, анимация, css-animation

Как реализовать покадровую анимацию создаваемую из `svg path`?
 То есть у меня есть, к примеру, 28 раскадрованых путей, и мне их надо показывать на экране друг за другом с задержкой `0.1с`. 
Как это реализовать? Если применить к ним `display:none;` -> `display:block` Не получается. Необходимо что-то по типу codepen.io/sdras/pen/LEzdea только для SVG графики

```css
.st3 {
  fill: #0e0e0d
}

.st7 {
  fill: #171615
}

.Girl {
  width: 100vw;
}

#L1{
  display:none;
}
#L2{
  display:none;
}
#L3{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<svg class="Girl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 960 550">
<path fill="#a3def9" d="M0 0h961.1v551.2H0z" id="_x30_"/>
    <g id="L1">
        <path class="st3"
              d="M818.8 207.9c-.4-1.7-.7-3.5-1.1-5.2.4-2.6-.6-3.7-3.2-3.5-2.5-.9-3-2.8-2.8-5.2.5-4.8 2.3-9.9 1.1-14.3-2.5-9.4 5-15.4 6.7-23.2.3-1.5 1.4-2.9 1.6-4.6 1.2-12.5 7.8-22.4 15.1-31.9 8.2-10.9 31.2-13 38.6 5.2.9 2.2 1.4 5.9 3.9 5.8 2.3-.1 2.5-3.9 3.6-6 3.5-6.6 6.2-13.5 9.1-20.4 4.1-9.4 12.5-15.5 18.9-23.1 9-10.7 17.2-22 23.3-34.6 2.8-5.7 5-11.6 1.4-18-1.1-1.9-.2-4.4.5-6.3 2.5-7.2 1.3-14.4.5-21.6 7.5 0 15 .1 22.5-.1 2.2 0 2.9.4 2.5 2.6-.1.6 0 1.3 0 2 0 180.2 0 360.3.1 540.5 0 4.2-.9 5.7-5.1 5.1-2.3-.4-4.7-.1-7-.1-2.5-108.5-5.1-217.1-7.6-325.6-.5-.1-.9-.2-1.4-.3-1 5.6-3.5 9.7-9.4 10.8-9.9 1.8-19.4 5.7-29.4 7.3-1.5.2-3.2.7-3.4 2.4-1.4 8.8-6.6 16.3-8.6 24.9-3.2 13.8-11.2 25-19.3 36.1-2 2.8-3.3 5.5-3.5 9-.5 15.1-.2 30.3-2.3 45.3-1.5 10.7-2.1 21.5-2.5 32.3-.2 6.4-1.9 12.5-4.4 18.1-2.1 4.6-3 9.1-2.5 14 1.1 9.2 2.2 18.5 3.4 27.7 2 15.9 5.6 31.3 13.2 45.6 5.5 10.3 9.5 21.2 11.9 32.6 1.5 7 4.8 12.4 12 13.6 4.7.8 5.3 2.4 3.8 6.2h-32c-1.2-6.1-2.6-12.1-6.8-17-.6-.7-1.2-1.8-2.3-1.6-1.3.2-.9 1.5-1.2 2.4-1.4 5.4-.8 10.8-.7 16.2h-2c-.8-8.4-1-17-5.1-24.6-3.2-5.8-2.2-11 1.8-15.6 2.6-3.1 2.8-5.9 1.7-9.6-3.2-11.2-8.2-21.7-13.2-32.2-11-23.3-14.3-47-7.2-72 .6-2.1 1.4-4.5-.4-6.7-1.7.7-1.9 2.3-2.5 3.6-3.6 8.1-7.8 15.7-13.7 22.3-2.2 2.5-4.7 4.8-5.9 8-6.4 17.3-13.6 34.2-18.6 52-2.9 10.4-4.2 21.1-5.9 31.8-1.7 10.5-5.6 20.4-10.5 29.9-1.4 2.6-1.2 4.7 2 5.1 4.9.7 6.8 4.8 9.4 8h-27c-2.6-5.8-3-11.9-3.1-18.2 0-3.5-.5-8.3-4.2-9.3-4.1-1.1-3.9 4.4-6 6.6-.2.3-.4.7-.6 1-.2.3-.3.7-.5 1-.2.3-.3.7-.5 1h-2c.2-.7.4-1.4.7-2.1.3-.2.4-.4.3-.7 1.3-6.3 2.9-12.6 2.9-19.1 0-4 6.1-9.3 10.7-8.8 5.8.6 8-3.1 10-7 3.1-5.8 3.6-12.3 4.4-18.7 1.7-13.5 2.7-27.1 5-40.6 1.8-10.8 7.4-20.3 13.5-29.2 9.1-13.3 15.3-27.5 17.6-43.4.9-5.9 2.5-11.8 4.9-17.2 4.5-10.1 4-20.3 2.5-30.8-1.1-7.6-1.6-15.3.1-22.8 2.3-10.3 8.8-17.8 18.1-22.6 5.1-2.6 9.5-6.1 13.9-9.6 5.7-4.5 6.4-12 1.6-18.1-5.8-7.5-12-14.6-18.1-21.9-1.1-1.3-2.3-2.5-4.2-1.6-1.1-.4-2.6.9-3.3-.9 3.6-2.7 3.4-4.6-.6-6.5-.4-1.2-1.1-2.1-2.5-2.3-.1-.6-.4-1-.7-1.3zM938 63.2c-1.2 1.7-1.6 2.2-1.9 2.8-7.6 15.4-16.9 29.7-26.7 43.7-4 5.7-8 11.4-10.7 17.9-3.8 9-7.5 18.1-12 26.8-2.4 4.7-2.5 8.4.4 12.4 1.5 2 1.8 3.9.3 5.9-2.3 3.1-5.5 5.7-2.5 10.4 2.2 3.6 4.1 7.4 8.1 9.1 3.1 1.2 5.5 2.9 7.3 5.5.3.5 1.5 0 1.2.9-.1.5-1.1 1.2-1.5 1.1-7-2.3-3.7 1.9-3 4.6.3 1 .3 2 .5 2.9.8 5.1-1.4 9.3-4.1 13.4-1.6 2.3-1.7 4.6-.3 7 1 1.6 2.4 2.2 4.2 2 7.9-1 15.8-1.9 23.6-3 3.5-.5 6.3-1.9 8.5-5.1 6.6-9.6 5.5-21.7 10.7-31.7.3-.7.1-1.6.1-2.5-.5-26.8-.8-53.6-1.5-80.4-.2-14-1-28.1-.7-43.7zM760 538.5c2.6-4.3 2.3-8.4 2.1-12.5-.1-1.7-1.1-2.8-2.9-2.6-1.5.2-2.6 1.4-2 2.9 1.6 3.7.4 7.9 2.8 12.2z"/>
        <path d="M742.1 533h2c-1.1 3.8-2.9 7.3-5.4 10.5.1-3.9 1.8-7.1 3.4-10.5z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="L2">
        <path d="M962 1v549.7h-12c-2.6-107.5-5.1-215.1-7.7-322.6-.4-.1-.8-.1-1.1-.2-.5.9-1.2 1.7-1.6 2.7-2.1 4.9-5.9 7.1-11.1 8.1-8.1 1.5-16.2 3.6-24.2 5.7-1 .3-2.1 1.6-2.4 2.7-3.5 10.5-6.2 21.4-10.6 31.6-4.1 9.7-9.6 18.9-15.2 27.9-3.1 5-5.4 9.7-5.8 15.9-1.6 22.2-4.5 44.3-6.1 66.5-.7 9.6-2.7 18.5-6.7 27.2-1.4 3.1-1 7.2-.7 10.8 1.8 21.5 3.2 43.1 11.3 63.5 3.2 8 7.2 15.7 10.3 23.8 2.4 6.3 4.4 12.9 5.8 19.5 1.7 7.7 6.8 11 13.8 12.4.8.2 1.5.4 2.4.6.1 3.5-1.7 4.3-4.7 4.3-8-.1-16-.3-24 0-3.7.1-5-1.5-5.7-4.6-1.1-5.3-3.1-10-7.1-13.6-.6 0-1.2.1-1.8.1-.3 6-.6 11.9-.9 17.9-.5 0-.9 0-1.4.1-.5-3.4-.8-6.9-1.6-10.2-1.4-5.2-3.6-10.3-4.6-15.6-.6-3.5-1.1-8.4.8-10.8 5.9-7.3 3.9-14.1.9-21.3-5-12.3-9.7-24.8-14.9-37-6.6-15.3-6.3-31-3.8-47 .3-2 .4-4 .6-5.3-17.5 16.8-25.3 39.4-33.4 61.5-4.4 12.1-6.7 24.9-10.5 37.3-3.6 11.5-7.7 22.9-12.1 34.1-1.6 4-1.3 5.7 2.8 7.4 2.7 1.1 4.7 3.9 8.2 6.9-9.3 0-17.1.2-24.8-.2-1.3-.1-3.3-2-3.6-3.3-.9-5-1.3-10.1-1.6-15.2-.2-3.9-1-7.5-5.5-10.9-3.8 7.1-7.4 13.8-11.1 20.5-.3-.1-.5-.2-.8-.3.4-1.2.8-2.3 1.1-3.5 2.3-9 4.8-17.9 6.8-26.9 1-4.4 5.6-9.3 11.1-9.2 6.7.1 9.8-3.9 11.2-9.1 2.4-8.8 3.9-17.8 5.8-26.7 2.9-13.8 2.1-28.3 9.2-41.1 4-7.3 7.9-14.7 12.8-21.3 9.8-13 12.9-28.3 16.2-43.6.7-3.2 1.1-6.7 2.5-9.6 6.3-12.9 4.7-26.2 2.4-39.6-3.1-18.4 2.2-30 18.1-40.1 4.5-2.9 8.9-5.9 12.8-9.5 7.1-6.6 6.1-10 1.1-15.5-6.3-6.9-11.7-14.5-17.6-21.7-1.8-2.1-4.4-3.6-6.7-5.5v-6.8c-2.6 2-4 3.2-6.1 4.8 1.6-7 1.4-12.6-4.4-16.8-1.2-.9-2-3.1-2-4.7 0-4.1.5-8.3.7-12.4.1-1.6.5-3.6-.2-4.9-1.8-3.3 0-5.3 1.3-8.1 3-6.1 5.9-12.4 7.5-19 3.1-12.6 8.3-24 17.8-32.8 8.1-7.6 28.1-8.6 34.8 6.6 1.2 2.8 2.8 5.5 4.8 9.4 3.7-8.4 7.5-15.6 10-23.2 2.9-8.8 7.7-16.1 14-22.7 12.4-13.2 22-28.4 29.7-44.7 2.3-4.9 3.7-10.1 1.5-15.9-.9-2.4.5-5.7 1-8.6.2-1.6.9-3.2.9-4.8.1-4.5.1-8.8.1-13.1h24zm-55.8 197.8c-2.3.3-4.6.6-7.3.9 4.1 7.9 3 14.7-1.4 21-2 2.9-1.9 6 .3 8.2 1.4 1.4 4.4 1.8 6.5 1.6 6.3-.6 12.5-1.5 18.7-2.6 1.7-.3 4-1 4.7-2.2 3.3-6.1 6.1-12.3 9-18.6.9-1.9 1.5-4 2-6.1.9-3.2 2.5-6.5 2.4-9.8-.6-42.1-1.5-84.3-2.3-126.4 0-1-.2-2-.4-3.6-.8.9-1.2 1.3-1.4 1.7-9.2 16.2-18.4 32.3-27.5 48.6-3.1 5.5-6.1 11-8.7 16.8-4.1 9.4-7.5 19.2-11.9 28.5-2 4.2-2.1 7.7.4 11.1 1.8 2.5 1.7 4.1-.4 6.5-2.7 3.1-3.1 6.2-.7 10.3 4.3 7.6 12.8 8.6 18 14.1zM760.4 536.4l1.8.3c.6-3.6 1.3-7.2 1.5-10.8 0-.8-1.9-1.7-2.9-2.6-.5 1.1-1.6 2.3-1.5 3.4.1 3.2.6 6.5 1.1 9.7z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="L3">
        <g class="st2">
            <path d="M823.9 210c-.3-1.4-.1-3.6-1-4.2-6.5-4.3-6.6-11.2-6-17.2.6-6.5-1.6-13.2 3.1-20 3.5-5.1 5.9-11.9 7.4-18.8 2.4-11.2 7.5-21.9 15.8-30 9.3-9.1 28.8-9.1 35.8 5.8 1.4 3 3.1 5.9 4.7 8.8.1.1.3.2.6.4 2.1-1.2 1.6-3.7 2.4-5.5 5.5-13 7.2-27.9 16.7-39 11.1-12.9 18.5-27.9 26.6-42.5 4.7-8.5 6.4-17.6 5.4-27.4-.7-6.3.9-12.8-.6-19.2 7.5 0 15 .1 22.5-.1 2.2 0 2.9.4 2.5 2.6-.1.6 0 1.3 0 2 0 180.2 0 360.3.1 540.5 0 4.2-.9 5.7-5.1 5.1-2.3-.4-4.7-.1-7-.1-2.5-107.2-5-214.4-7.5-321.5-4.2 5.7-8.5 8.9-15.2 9.6-4.8.5-9.5 2.6-14.3 4-1.4.4-2.6 1.2-2.7 2.6-1 8.2-5.5 15.3-7.1 23.3-3 15-8.6 28.9-17.9 41.2-2 2.7-3.3 5.8-4.1 9-3.1 12.4-6.3 24.7-7.8 37.5-1.5 12.4-3.9 24.6-5.2 37-.7 6.6-2.2 12.8-5.1 18.4-2.3 4.4-3 8.6-3 13.3-.2 12.9 1.6 25.6 3 38.3 1.5 13.4 5.2 26.2 11.2 38.4 4.8 10 8.6 20.4 10.6 31.4 1.3 7.3 6 11.7 12.9 12.6 4 .5 3.4 2.4 3.3 4.8h-33c-1.5-5.7-2.8-11.5-6.7-16.2-.6-.7-1.1-1.8-2.3-1.6-1.3.3-1.1 1.5-1.2 2.4-.3 5.1-.5 10.2-.8 15.4h-2c-.5-8.1-1.2-16.3-5.1-23.5-3.2-5.9-2.2-11 1.7-15.6 3.1-3.7 3.2-7.6 2-11.7-1.5-5-3.4-10-5.2-14.9-6-16.1-12.8-31.9-15.7-49.1-.7-4.4.7-8.9-.6-13.6-2.8 2.1-4.2 4.6-5.5 7.3-3.1 6.4-6.4 12.8-9.5 19.2-6.4 13.3-13.5 26.2-18.2 40.3-3.8 11.4-6.2 23.3-11.5 34.3-2.3 4.8-6 8.8-8.2 13.6-1.2 2.7-2.2 4.5 1.8 6 3 1.1 4.8 4 3.9 7.7h-21c-4.1-5-4-10.6-2.8-16.5.8-3.9 1.4-7.9-.3-11.7-1.9-4.2-3.2-4.2-6.1-.5-3 3.9-4.5 9.2-10.1 12.7 1.1-2.5 1.5-4 2.3-5.2 3.9-6.3 6.2-13.1 7.6-20.3 1-5.3 6.7-10.3 12-9.5 6.2.9 9-2.8 11.1-7.1 3.9-8 5.2-16.7 7.4-25.3 3.3-12.6 4.4-25.9 10.2-37.8 4.1-8.4 9.5-16 15.3-23.3 9.4-11.9 12.6-26.2 14.9-40.8.9-5.8 2.1-11.5 4.2-16.9 4.1-10.8 3.1-21.1-1.1-31.5-5-12.5-3.8-24.4 4.1-35.4 2.4-3.4 5.4-6.4 9-8.5 6.1-3.6 11.1-8.5 16.5-12.8 1.3-1 2.3-2.5 3-3.9.8-1.6.5-3.3-1.9-2.5-2.9 1.1-4.3-.7-5.9-2.4-9.4-10.8-17.3-22.7-23.3-35.7 0-.8 0-1.6-1.2-.8-.3.1-.5.2-.7.5-2-.6-.7-1.7-.4-2.6.6-1.9.3-3.1-1.7-3.3zm88.8-11.2c-1.8 0-2.9-.1-4.1 0-1.4.1-3.1-1.4-4.2 0s.5 2.8 1.1 4c1.6 3.3 1.5 6.7.9 10.2-.6 3.5-2.3 6.5-3.8 9.7-1.4 3.2.6 8.2 3.1 7.9 10.2-1.3 21.1-1 26.3-13.1 1.5-3.5 3.7-6.6 3.6-10.6-.1-1.8.8-3.2 1.8-4.5 1.9-2.4 2.2-4.9 2.2-7.9-.7-27.8-1.2-55.6-1.8-83.4-.4-16.2-1.4-32.3-1.4-48.6-.7.5-1.1 1-1.3 1.5-4.7 12.6-11.1 24.4-17.3 36.3-5.3 10.1-11.3 19.8-14.4 31-3.1 11-5.7 22.2-11.6 32.1-1.3 2.2-.8 4.3.8 5.9 1.7 1.8 1.2 3.4.2 5.4-3 6.1.2 14.8 6.8 16.8 4.7 1.7 8.6 4 13.1 7.3zM763.4 533.2c2.5-3.1 3.5-6 3.4-9.4-.1-1.7-.8-2.9-2.7-2.7-1.6.2-2.2 1.4-2 2.9.3 2.8.8 5.6 1.3 9.2z"/>
            <path d="M823.9 210c2 .2 2.3 1.4 1.8 3-.2.9-1.6 2 .4 2.6.1 2.3-2.1 2.2-3.3 3-1.1.7-2.2-.6-1.3-1.4 2.2-2.1.8-5.1 2.4-7.2zM826.8 215.1c1.2-.8 1.1 0 1.2.8-.4-.2-.8-.5-1.2-.8z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: наверно обычный слайдер изображений slick справится с этим, только уменьшить паузу между слайдами так как по дефолту у него 3 сек ...вместо слайда показать ваш SVG  ну и разумеется сделать его вертикальным  и всё

Comment: что бы не захломлять html разметку вынести svg разметку в отдельный файл и от туда выводить уже в slick разметку

Comment: это примерная реализация : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/pOpZVo?editors=0110

Comment: @BlackStar1991 задержка 0.1 s или 1s между кадрами? Добавь svg код 2-3-х патчей для предметного ответа. Я кажется знаю, как решить твою задачу

Comment: Добавил кадры, и да 100мс (ну мне бы концепцию понять). Хотелось бы без добавления  сторонних библиотек. Да и после того как этот мультик отыграет, там хотелось бы ещё анимацию прикрутить в другой части экрана

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Суть решения, чтобы показывать через равные промежутки кадры, заключается в использовании команды анимации  svg `animate` c параметром `calcMode="discrete"`
 Если нужно показать 28 кадров, каждый из которых длится `0.1s`, то общее время анимации будет `dur="2.8s"`

В вопросе автора три кадра, поэтому временные значения будут другие.

**Структура анимации**

Анимируется параметр `"d"`  патча, так как именно в нем хранится изображение каждого кадра. В процессе анимации идет дискретное изменение этого параметра `"d"`

```
<Path d="M818.8 ...(первый кадр) >
 <animate attributeName="d" values="M818.8 ...(первый кадр);
 M962 1v549.7h...(второй кадр);
<!-- У последнего кадра нет точки с запятой в конце --> 
M823.9 ... (третий кадр)" 
 dur="1s" calcMode="discrete"
</path>
```

Другими словами из каждого патча, отвечающего за один кадр берется значение параметра `"d"` и подставляются в атрибут `values` через точку с запятой `;`. Последний кадр не имеет точки с запятой.

```css
.st3 {
  fill: #0e0e0d
}

.st7 {
  fill: #171615
}

.Girl {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<svg id="Girl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 960 550">
<path fill="#a3def9" d="M0 0h961.1v551.2H0z" id="_x30_"/>
    <g id="L1">
        <path class="st3"
              d="M818.8 207.9c-.4-1.7-.7-3.5-1.1-5.2.4-2.6-.6-3.7-3.2-3.5-2.5-.9-3-2.8-2.8-5.2.5-4.8 2.3-9.9 1.1-14.3-2.5-9.4 5-15.4 6.7-23.2.3-1.5 1.4-2.9 1.6-4.6 1.2-12.5 7.8-22.4 15.1-31.9 8.2-10.9 31.2-13 38.6 5.2.9 2.2 1.4 5.9 3.9 5.8 2.3-.1 2.5-3.9 3.6-6 3.5-6.6 6.2-13.5 9.1-20.4 4.1-9.4 12.5-15.5 18.9-23.1 9-10.7 17.2-22 23.3-34.6 2.8-5.7 5-11.6 1.4-18-1.1-1.9-.2-4.4.5-6.3 2.5-7.2 1.3-14.4.5-21.6 7.5 0 15 .1 22.5-.1 2.2 0 2.9.4 2.5 2.6-.1.6 0 1.3 0 2 0 180.2 0 360.3.1 540.5 0 4.2-.9 5.7-5.1 5.1-2.3-.4-4.7-.1-7-.1-2.5-108.5-5.1-217.1-7.6-325.6-.5-.1-.9-.2-1.4-.3-1 5.6-3.5 9.7-9.4 10.8-9.9 1.8-19.4 5.7-29.4 7.3-1.5.2-3.2.7-3.4 2.4-1.4 8.8-6.6 16.3-8.6 24.9-3.2 13.8-11.2 25-19.3 36.1-2 2.8-3.3 5.5-3.5 9-.5 15.1-.2 30.3-2.3 45.3-1.5 10.7-2.1 21.5-2.5 32.3-.2 6.4-1.9 12.5-4.4 18.1-2.1 4.6-3 9.1-2.5 14 1.1 9.2 2.2 18.5 3.4 27.7 2 15.9 5.6 31.3 13.2 45.6 5.5 10.3 9.5 21.2 11.9 32.6 1.5 7 4.8 12.4 12 13.6 4.7.8 5.3 2.4 3.8 6.2h-32c-1.2-6.1-2.6-12.1-6.8-17-.6-.7-1.2-1.8-2.3-1.6-1.3.2-.9 1.5-1.2 2.4-1.4 5.4-.8 10.8-.7 16.2h-2c-.8-8.4-1-17-5.1-24.6-3.2-5.8-2.2-11 1.8-15.6 2.6-3.1 2.8-5.9 1.7-9.6-3.2-11.2-8.2-21.7-13.2-32.2-11-23.3-14.3-47-7.2-72 .6-2.1 1.4-4.5-.4-6.7-1.7.7-1.9 2.3-2.5 3.6-3.6 8.1-7.8 15.7-13.7 22.3-2.2 2.5-4.7 4.8-5.9 8-6.4 17.3-13.6 34.2-18.6 52-2.9 10.4-4.2 21.1-5.9 31.8-1.7 10.5-5.6 20.4-10.5 29.9-1.4 2.6-1.2 4.7 2 5.1 4.9.7 6.8 4.8 9.4 8h-27c-2.6-5.8-3-11.9-3.1-18.2 0-3.5-.5-8.3-4.2-9.3-4.1-1.1-3.9 4.4-6 6.6-.2.3-.4.7-.6 1-.2.3-.3.7-.5 1-.2.3-.3.7-.5 1h-2c.2-.7.4-1.4.7-2.1.3-.2.4-.4.3-.7 1.3-6.3 2.9-12.6 2.9-19.1 0-4 6.1-9.3 10.7-8.8 5.8.6 8-3.1 10-7 3.1-5.8 3.6-12.3 4.4-18.7 1.7-13.5 2.7-27.1 5-40.6 1.8-10.8 7.4-20.3 13.5-29.2 9.1-13.3 15.3-27.5 17.6-43.4.9-5.9 2.5-11.8 4.9-17.2 4.5-10.1 4-20.3 2.5-30.8-1.1-7.6-1.6-15.3.1-22.8 2.3-10.3 8.8-17.8 18.1-22.6 5.1-2.6 9.5-6.1 13.9-9.6 5.7-4.5 6.4-12 1.6-18.1-5.8-7.5-12-14.6-18.1-21.9-1.1-1.3-2.3-2.5-4.2-1.6-1.1-.4-2.6.9-3.3-.9 3.6-2.7 3.4-4.6-.6-6.5-.4-1.2-1.1-2.1-2.5-2.3-.1-.6-.4-1-.7-1.3zM938 63.2c-1.2 1.7-1.6 2.2-1.9 2.8-7.6 15.4-16.9 29.7-26.7 43.7-4 5.7-8 11.4-10.7 17.9-3.8 9-7.5 18.1-12 26.8-2.4 4.7-2.5 8.4.4 12.4 1.5 2 1.8 3.9.3 5.9-2.3 3.1-5.5 5.7-2.5 10.4 2.2 3.6 4.1 7.4 8.1 9.1 3.1 1.2 5.5 2.9 7.3 5.5.3.5 1.5 0 1.2.9-.1.5-1.1 1.2-1.5 1.1-7-2.3-3.7 1.9-3 4.6.3 1 .3 2 .5 2.9.8 5.1-1.4 9.3-4.1 13.4-1.6 2.3-1.7 4.6-.3 7 1 1.6 2.4 2.2 4.2 2 7.9-1 15.8-1.9 23.6-3 3.5-.5 6.3-1.9 8.5-5.1 6.6-9.6 5.5-21.7 10.7-31.7.3-.7.1-1.6.1-2.5-.5-26.8-.8-53.6-1.5-80.4-.2-14-1-28.1-.7-43.7zM760 538.5c2.6-4.3 2.3-8.4 2.1-12.5-.1-1.7-1.1-2.8-2.9-2.6-1.5.2-2.6 1.4-2 2.9 1.6 3.7.4 7.9 2.8 12.2z">
    
    <animate attributeName="d" values="M962 1v549.7h-12c-2.6-107.5-5.1-215.1-7.7-322.6-.4-.1-.8-.1-1.1-.2-.5.9-1.2 1.7-1.6 2.7-2.1 4.9-5.9 7.1-11.1 8.1-8.1 1.5-16.2 3.6-24.2 5.7-1 .3-2.1 1.6-2.4 2.7-3.5 10.5-6.2 21.4-10.6 31.6-4.1 9.7-9.6 18.9-15.2 27.9-3.1 5-5.4 9.7-5.8 15.9-1.6 22.2-4.5 44.3-6.1 66.5-.7 9.6-2.7 18.5-6.7 27.2-1.4 3.1-1 7.2-.7 10.8 1.8 21.5 3.2 43.1 11.3 63.5 3.2 8 7.2 15.7 10.3 23.8 2.4 6.3 4.4 12.9 5.8 19.5 1.7 7.7 6.8 11 13.8 12.4.8.2 1.5.4 2.4.6.1 3.5-1.7 4.3-4.7 4.3-8-.1-16-.3-24 0-3.7.1-5-1.5-5.7-4.6-1.1-5.3-3.1-10-7.1-13.6-.6 0-1.2.1-1.8.1-.3 6-.6 11.9-.9 17.9-.5 0-.9 0-1.4.1-.5-3.4-.8-6.9-1.6-10.2-1.4-5.2-3.6-10.3-4.6-15.6-.6-3.5-1.1-8.4.8-10.8 5.9-7.3 3.9-14.1.9-21.3-5-12.3-9.7-24.8-14.9-37-6.6-15.3-6.3-31-3.8-47 .3-2 .4-4 .6-5.3-17.5 16.8-25.3 39.4-33.4 61.5-4.4 12.1-6.7 24.9-10.5 37.3-3.6 11.5-7.7 22.9-12.1 34.1-1.6 4-1.3 5.7 2.8 7.4 2.7 1.1 4.7 3.9 8.2 6.9-9.3 0-17.1.2-24.8-.2-1.3-.1-3.3-2-3.6-3.3-.9-5-1.3-10.1-1.6-15.2-.2-3.9-1-7.5-5.5-10.9-3.8 7.1-7.4 13.8-11.1 20.5-.3-.1-.5-.2-.8-.3.4-1.2.8-2.3 1.1-3.5 2.3-9 4.8-17.9 6.8-26.9 1-4.4 5.6-9.3 11.1-9.2 6.7.1 9.8-3.9 11.2-9.1 2.4-8.8 3.9-17.8 5.8-26.7 2.9-13.8 2.1-28.3 9.2-41.1 4-7.3 7.9-14.7 12.8-21.3 9.8-13 12.9-28.3 16.2-43.6.7-3.2 1.1-6.7 2.5-9.6 6.3-12.9 4.7-26.2 2.4-39.6-3.1-18.4 2.2-30 18.1-40.1 4.5-2.9 8.9-5.9 12.8-9.5 7.1-6.6 6.1-10 1.1-15.5-6.3-6.9-11.7-14.5-17.6-21.7-1.8-2.1-4.4-3.6-6.7-5.5v-6.8c-2.6 2-4 3.2-6.1 4.8 1.6-7 1.4-12.6-4.4-16.8-1.2-.9-2-3.1-2-4.7 0-4.1.5-8.3.7-12.4.1-1.6.5-3.6-.2-4.9-1.8-3.3 0-5.3 1.3-8.1 3-6.1 5.9-12.4 7.5-19 3.1-12.6 8.3-24 17.8-32.8 8.1-7.6 28.1-8.6 34.8 6.6 1.2 2.8 2.8 5.5 4.8 9.4 3.7-8.4 7.5-15.6 10-23.2 2.9-8.8 7.7-16.1 14-22.7 12.4-13.2 22-28.4 29.7-44.7 2.3-4.9 3.7-10.1 1.5-15.9-.9-2.4.5-5.7 1-8.6.2-1.6.9-3.2.9-4.8.1-4.5.1-8.8.1-13.1h24zm-55.8 197.8c-2.3.3-4.6.6-7.3.9 4.1 7.9 3 14.7-1.4 21-2 2.9-1.9 6 .3 8.2 1.4 1.4 4.4 1.8 6.5 1.6 6.3-.6 12.5-1.5 18.7-2.6 1.7-.3 4-1 4.7-2.2 3.3-6.1 6.1-12.3 9-18.6.9-1.9 1.5-4 2-6.1.9-3.2 2.5-6.5 2.4-9.8-.6-42.1-1.5-84.3-2.3-126.4 0-1-.2-2-.4-3.6-.8.9-1.2 1.3-1.4 1.7-9.2 16.2-18.4 32.3-27.5 48.6-3.1 5.5-6.1 11-8.7 16.8-4.1 9.4-7.5 19.2-11.9 28.5-2 4.2-2.1 7.7.4 11.1 1.8 2.5 1.7 4.1-.4 6.5-2.7 3.1-3.1 6.2-.7 10.3 4.3 7.6 12.8 8.6 18 14.1zM760.4 536.4l1.8.3c.6-3.6 1.3-7.2 1.5-10.8 0-.8-1.9-1.7-2.9-2.6-.5 1.1-1.6 2.3-1.5 3.4.1 3.2.6 6.5 1.1 9.7z;M823.9 210c-.3-1.4-.1-3.6-1-4.2-6.5-4.3-6.6-11.2-6-17.2.6-6.5-1.6-13.2 3.1-20 3.5-5.1 5.9-11.9 7.4-18.8 2.4-11.2 7.5-21.9 15.8-30 9.3-9.1 28.8-9.1 35.8 5.8 1.4 3 3.1 5.9 4.7 8.8.1.1.3.2.6.4 2.1-1.2 1.6-3.7 2.4-5.5 5.5-13 7.2-27.9 16.7-39 11.1-12.9 18.5-27.9 26.6-42.5 4.7-8.5 6.4-17.6 5.4-27.4-.7-6.3.9-12.8-.6-19.2 7.5 0 15 .1 22.5-.1 2.2 0 2.9.4 2.5 2.6-.1.6 0 1.3 0 2 0 180.2 0 360.3.1 540.5 0 4.2-.9 5.7-5.1 5.1-2.3-.4-4.7-.1-7-.1-2.5-107.2-5-214.4-7.5-321.5-4.2 5.7-8.5 8.9-15.2 9.6-4.8.5-9.5 2.6-14.3 4-1.4.4-2.6 1.2-2.7 2.6-1 8.2-5.5 15.3-7.1 23.3-3 15-8.6 28.9-17.9 41.2-2 2.7-3.3 5.8-4.1 9-3.1 12.4-6.3 24.7-7.8 37.5-1.5 12.4-3.9 24.6-5.2 37-.7 6.6-2.2 12.8-5.1 18.4-2.3 4.4-3 8.6-3 13.3-.2 12.9 1.6 25.6 3 38.3 1.5 13.4 5.2 26.2 11.2 38.4 4.8 10 8.6 20.4 10.6 31.4 1.3 7.3 6 11.7 12.9 12.6 4 .5 3.4 2.4 3.3 4.8h-33c-1.5-5.7-2.8-11.5-6.7-16.2-.6-.7-1.1-1.8-2.3-1.6-1.3.3-1.1 1.5-1.2 2.4-.3 5.1-.5 10.2-.8 15.4h-2c-.5-8.1-1.2-16.3-5.1-23.5-3.2-5.9-2.2-11 1.7-15.6 3.1-3.7 3.2-7.6 2-11.7-1.5-5-3.4-10-5.2-14.9-6-16.1-12.8-31.9-15.7-49.1-.7-4.4.7-8.9-.6-13.6-2.8 2.1-4.2 4.6-5.5 7.3-3.1 6.4-6.4 12.8-9.5 19.2-6.4 13.3-13.5 26.2-18.2 40.3-3.8 11.4-6.2 23.3-11.5 34.3-2.3 4.8-6 8.8-8.2 13.6-1.2 2.7-2.2 4.5 1.8 6 3 1.1 4.8 4 3.9 7.7h-21c-4.1-5-4-10.6-2.8-16.5.8-3.9 1.4-7.9-.3-11.7-1.9-4.2-3.2-4.2-6.1-.5-3 3.9-4.5 9.2-10.1 12.7 1.1-2.5 1.5-4 2.3-5.2 3.9-6.3 6.2-13.1 7.6-20.3 1-5.3 6.7-10.3 12-9.5 6.2.9 9-2.8 11.1-7.1 3.9-8 5.2-16.7 7.4-25.3 3.3-12.6 4.4-25.9 10.2-37.8 4.1-8.4 9.5-16 15.3-23.3 9.4-11.9 12.6-26.2 14.9-40.8.9-5.8 2.1-11.5 4.2-16.9 4.1-10.8 3.1-21.1-1.1-31.5-5-12.5-3.8-24.4 4.1-35.4 2.4-3.4 5.4-6.4 9-8.5 6.1-3.6 11.1-8.5 16.5-12.8 1.3-1 2.3-2.5 3-3.9.8-1.6.5-3.3-1.9-2.5-2.9 1.1-4.3-.7-5.9-2.4-9.4-10.8-17.3-22.7-23.3-35.7 0-.8 0-1.6-1.2-.8-.3.1-.5.2-.7.5-2-.6-.7-1.7-.4-2.6.6-1.9.3-3.1-1.7-3.3zm88.8-11.2c-1.8 0-2.9-.1-4.1 0-1.4.1-3.1-1.4-4.2 0s.5 2.8 1.1 4c1.6 3.3 1.5 6.7.9 10.2-.6 3.5-2.3 6.5-3.8 9.7-1.4 3.2.6 8.2 3.1 7.9 10.2-1.3 21.1-1 26.3-13.1 1.5-3.5 3.7-6.6 3.6-10.6-.1-1.8.8-3.2 1.8-4.5 1.9-2.4 2.2-4.9 2.2-7.9-.7-27.8-1.2-55.6-1.8-83.4-.4-16.2-1.4-32.3-1.4-48.6-.7.5-1.1 1-1.3 1.5-4.7 12.6-11.1 24.4-17.3 36.3-5.3 10.1-11.3 19.8-14.4 31-3.1 11-5.7 22.2-11.6 32.1-1.3 2.2-.8 4.3.8 5.9 1.7 1.8 1.2 3.4.2 5.4-3 6.1.2 14.8 6.8 16.8 4.7 1.7 8.6 4 13.1 7.3zM763.4 533.2c2.5-3.1 3.5-6 3.4-9.4-.1-1.7-.8-2.9-2.7-2.7-1.6.2-2.2 1.4-2 2.9.3 2.8.8 5.6 1.3 9.2z" dur="0.5s" calcMode="discrete" begin=Girl.click />
            
     </path> 
  
  <text x="500" y="100" font-size="36"> Click me</text>
 
   
    </svg>
```

Приложение адаптивно и работает во всех современных браузерах, кроме **IE**

Можно попробовать использовать анимацию спрайтов CSS, которая работает и в браузере `IE11`

Ниже ссылка на анимацию спрайта CSS

[Анимация персонажа прыгающей девочки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/841252/28748)

Comment: Александр ты как обычно ..бесподобен ...плюсик от меня ..мог бы оценить больше - поставил бы 100 плюсиков

Comment: только вот как обычно не работает в Edge , хотелось бы увидеть анимации SVG именно в Edge

Comment: Спасибо, за совет. Как закончу, обязательно выложу что вышло =)

Comment: @user33274 анимация патчей и других кривых не работает в браузерах IE и не будет работать в будущем, как заявляют тор менеджеры Microsoft

Comment: @BlackStar1991 посмотри,  добавил описание внизу топика, может будет полезно. Самое трудное в той технике найти правильный спрайт, который не косячит наложением фрагментов изображений при переходе кадров.

Comment: Ещё раз, спасибо. Как обещал делюсь результатом https://codepen.io/BlackStar1991/pen/QZgqgv

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Круто получилось, поздравляю, класс растёт!

Comment: @BlackStar1991 И эта, твоя работа очень понравилась https://codepen.io/BlackStar1991/details/RJWqmg/