# Анимация персонажа с использованием svg совместно с параллаксом фона

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Есть задача анимировать растровый спрайт, используя анимацию `smil svg`, идущего человека совместно с анимацией (параллаксом) фона.

Картинка спрайта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинки фона гор, травы взяты с сайта: - http://rachelnabors.com/
Сейчас затрудняюсь сказать, кто автор рисунков, так как встречал подобное на многих сайтах. Буду благодарен тому, кто укажет адрес правообладателя.

картинка части горного фона

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 10):

### Анимация идущего человека

- Спрайт имеет размеры `width="624"` `height="450"`
- Будем анимировать первую строку из трех, поэтому минимальная
  высота окна просмотра -`150px`
- В строке 6 позиций, ширина одной позиции `624 / 6 = 104px`
  Итого
  габариты просмотрового окна, через который будет протягиваться
  спрайт - `104x150px`
  Именно такие размеры зададим - `viewBox = "0 0 104 150"`, чтобы    умещалась ровно одна позиция (картинка) спрайта.
- Спрайт добавляем с помощью тега `<image>`

```css
.bg {
 position:relative 
  left:40%;
  bottom:10%;
 }

.cont {
position:absolute;
bottom:3%;
left:40%;
z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
<div class="cont">
<svg id="svg2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="104" height="150" viewBox="0 0 104 150" >  
<image id="man" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTWkv.png" x="0" y="0" width="624" height="450" >
 <animate attributeName="x" values=" -520;-416;-312;-208;-104;0" dur="0.75s"  calcMode="discrete" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
</image> 
</svg>   
</div> 
</div>
```

### Анимация параллакса фона

Фон состоит из двух background травы, из пяти контуров гор.
По законам физического восприятия, чем дальше предмет, тем он должен медленнее перемещаться.

Поэтому трава на переднем плане перемещается с наибольшей скоростью, второй фон травы медленнее и горы вдали имеют самую маленькую скорость перемещения.

Реализация анимация перемещения, однотипна для всех элементов:

*Интересней смотреть в полноэкранном режиме*

```
.foreground {
  animation: parallax_fg linear 30s infinite both;
  background:  url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc1NS.png) 0 100% repeat-x;
  z-index: 4;
}
@keyframes parallax_fg {  
  0% { background-position: 3584px 100%;} 
  100% {background-position: 0 100%; } 
}
```

```css
.bg {
 
 width: 230px;
  height: 636px;
  left:40%;
  bottom:0;
  position:relative;
 }

.cont {
position:absolute;
bottom:-35%;
left:40%;
z-index: 3;
} 
.foreground, .midground, .background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  translate3d(0,0,0); 
}
.foreground {
  animation: parallax_fg linear 30s infinite both;
  background:  url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc1NS.png) 0 100% repeat-x;
  z-index: 4;
  pointer-events: none;
}
@keyframes parallax_fg {  
  0% { background-position: 3584px 100%;} 
  100% {background-position: 0 100%; } 
}
.midground {
  animation: parallax_mg linear 60s infinite;
  background:  url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFO4j.png) 0 100% repeat-x;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}
@keyframes parallax_mg {  
  0% { background-position: 3000px 100%;} 
  100% {background-position: 0 100%; } 
}
.background {
  background-image:
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH0A3.png),
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYelb.png),
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqP3B.png),
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnQHp.png),
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5GYi.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  animation: parallax_bg linear 180s infinite;
  
}
@keyframes parallax_bg {
  100% { background-position-x: 1200px, 1600px, 1800px, 2000px, 2400px;}
}
body {
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%),
    #d2d2d2 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WuXS.png);
}
.play_audio {

position:absolute;
top:0%;
left:0%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="150" height="35" wiewBox="0 0 150 35"  >
<g id="btn1" onclick='play()' >
     <rect  x="30" y="0" width="70" height="30" rx="15" fill="black" /> 
     <text id="txt1" x="44" y="21" font-size="22px" fill="white" >Start</text>
 </g>
</svg> 
 <div class="foreground"></div> 
 <div class="midground"> </div> 
 <div class="background"> </div> 
 <div class="bg">
<div class="cont"> 

<svg id="svg2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="104" height="150" viewBox="0 0 104 150" >  
<image id="man1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTWkv.png" x="0" y="0" width="624" height="450" >
 <animate id="an_man1" attributeName="x" begin="btn1.click" values=" -520;-416;-312;-208;-104;0" dur="0.75s"  calcMode="discrete" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
</image> 
</svg>
  </div> 
 </div>   
<script>
var zodiac = new Audio();
zodiac.src = 'https://svg-art.ru/files/Come_Together.mp3';

function play() {
  zodiac.play();
}
</script>
```

### Update 06.04.2019

Добавлен аудиоплейер, так как `Chrome` перестал воспроизводить файлы `*.mp3` в режиме автоматического запуска.

Во время анимации звучит трек - `Come Together` из альбома `Abbey Road` группы `Beatles`

Comment: Alexandr_TT, привет...  Прикольный пример....