# Анимация пешеходных и других маршрутов на растровой карте

Tags: html, css3, svg, анимация

Возникла идея, как сделать анимацию похода с семьей в ТЮЗ г. Санкт-Петербурга, допустим для жителей Ленинградской области. Чтобы реализовать анимацию нескольких маршрутов.

Маршрут движения будет на поезде до вокзала и  пешком собственно до театра.

*Это учебный пример, где будет использованs несколько техник реализации анимации:*

1. Анимация поезда,- составленного из символов юникода, который движется вдоль заданного пути, проложенного на растровой карте.
2. Анимация рисования пешеходного маршрута от вокзала до ТЮЗ'а.
3. Анимация фигурок взрослых и их детей.
4. Анимация движения персонажей вдоль заданного маршрута.

Ниже пример одной части анимации - прокладка пешеходного маршрута

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1" width="800" height="540" viewBox="0 0 800 540" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
  
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPdWW.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <path id="train" stroke-dasharray="312" stroke-dashoffset="312" stroke-width="2" d="M443 534 426 477 415 435 397 391 375 347 350 304 334 277 317 251" style="fill:none;stroke:violet;"/>
 
  <path id="walk" stroke-dasharray="409" stroke-dashoffset="409" stroke-width="2" d="m343 268 34-10 50-9-33-86 22-14 7-21 8-3 13 18 34-25 47 65 22-19"  style="fill:none;stroke:#B34EE9">
  <animate id="anWalk" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="6s" values="409;0;409" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>

</svg>
```

*Как сделать, перечисленные выше, виды анимации?*

Comment: А что это за новая мода? Сам спросил сам ответил?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q это распространенная практика всех сайтов stackoverflow - делиться знаниями в форме вопрос-ответ, которая только приветствуется администрацией.

Comment: тогда тут не хватает тега FAQ

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, тег FAQ (frequently asked questions) нужен для часто задаваемых вопросов. Что-то мне подсказывает, что это не очень часто задаваемый вопрос. Для самоответа этот тег не нужен. Самоответ вообще ничем не отличается от обычного вопроса - ответа (если не считать, что задающий вопрос и отвечающий один и тот же), поэтому никаких дополнительных тегов не нужно.

Answer (score 27):

Буду поэтапно, подробно объяснять все фрагменты анимации.
Отдельные куски могут быть использованы для оживления раздела "Контакты" сайта заказчика.
Опираясь на описание, можно добавить собственные карты и проложить необходимы маршруты.

### Добавление растровой карты в SVG

Для внедрения выбранного фрагмента растровой карты в SVG используется тег `<image>`

```
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPdWW.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

### Прорисовка маршрутов движения поезда и людей

- Загружаем карту в векторный редактор и инструментом `"Рисовать кривые Безье"` добавляем узловые точки на  маршруты движения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохраняем файл в формате `*.svg` и копируем из него патчи маршрутов

*Вычисляем длину маршрутов:*

для поезда это будет - `312px`
пешеходный маршрут - `409px`

- Пишем команду анимации для пешеходного маршрута

```
   <path id="walk" stroke-dasharray="409" stroke-dashoffset="409" stroke-width="2" d="m343 268 34-10 50-9-33-86 22-14 7-21 8-3 13 18 34-25 47 65 22-19"  style="fill:none;stroke:#B34EE9">
      <animate id="anWalk" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="6s" values="409;0;409" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </path>
```

### Анимация поезда,- составленного из символов юникода

Юникод вагона - `&#128643;`  Перемычки между вагонами - `&#45;`

Поезд будет идти по маршруту:

```
<path id="train"  stroke-width="2" d="M443 534 426 477 415 435 397 391 375 347 350 304 334 277 317 251" style="fill:none;stroke:none;"/>
```

*Ниже код поезда без анимации людей:*

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1" width="800" height="540" viewBox="0 0 800 540" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
  
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPdWW.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <path id="train"
   stroke-dasharray="312"
   stroke-dashoffset="312"
   stroke-width="2"
   d="M443 534 426 477 415 435 397 391 375 347 350 304 334 277 317 251"
   style="fill:none;stroke:violet;"/>
    
  <text
   font-size="28"
   font-family="Times New Roman"
   fill="#517DA6" >
<textPath id="result"
 xlink:href="#train">
<tspan dx="0" > &#128642; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">  &#45; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">   &#45;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-15">   &#128643; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">   &#45; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">   &#45;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-15">   &#128643; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">   &#45; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">   &#45;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-15" >   &#128642; </tspan>
<animate id="anTrain"
   begin="0s"
   dur="12s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   attributeName="startOffset"
   values="-60%;45%;45%;-60%"
   fill="freeze"/> 
</textPath>
</text>     
  
</svg>
```

Команда анимации движения поезда здесь будет несколько иная в отличии
от анимации пешеходного маршрута, так как необходимо запустить по
одному маршруту несколько вагонов.

```
<animate id="anTrain"  dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinity"
attributeName="startOffset" values="-60%;45%;45%;-60%"
fill="freeze"/>`
```

*Ниже код анимации поезда:*

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1" width="800" height="540" viewBox="0 0 800 540" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
  
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPdWW.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <path id="train"
  stroke-width="2" 
  d="M443 534 426 477 415 435 397 391 375 347 350 304 334 277 317 251"
  style="fill:none;stroke:none;"/>
     
  <text
   font-size="28"
   font-family="Times New Roman"
   fill="#517DA6" >
<textPath id="result"    xlink:href="#train">
<tspan dx="0" > &#128643; </tspan> <tspan dx="-12">  &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan><tspan dx="-12">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#128643; </tspan><tspan dx="-12">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan><tspan dx="-12">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#128643; </tspan><tspan dx="-12">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan><tspan dx="-12">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15" >   &#128643; </tspan>
 <animate id="anTrain"  dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinity" attributeName="startOffset" values="-60%;45%;45%;-60%" fill="freeze"/> 
</textPath>
</text>     
  
</svg>
```

### Анимация фигурок взрослых и их детей

Анимация движения людей основана на анимации параметра `"d"` нескольких`<path>` для фигуры человека в нескольких фазах ходьбы, что при быстрой смене значений `"d"` создаёт иллюзию ходьбы.

*Ниже код анимации:*

```html
 <svg width="400px" height="300px" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="www://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background:skyblue;">
 <!-- Man -->
  <g transform="translate(240,270) scale(1,-1)">
    <path stroke="#000"  fill="none">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                      type="translate" values="0;-100;0" dur="16s"
        begin="1s" fill="freeze"/>
        <animate attributeName="d" begin="0.1s" dur="0.3s" repeatCount="indefinite"
          values="M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M 0,0 0,10 0,0 M0,10 0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0"/>
    </path>
  </g>
  </svg>
```

### Собираем все фрагменты анимации вместе

Тайминг в `SMIL` `SVG` анимации просчитывается и реализуется довольно просто, в отличии от анимации `CSS`

- Если нужно запустить вторую анимацию строго после окончания первой
  анимации, то  применяется следующая запись: `begin="an1.end"`, где
  `an1` - уникальный идентификатор первой анимации.
- Если вторая анимация должна запуститься через `1 сек.` после
  окончания первой анимации, то - `begin="an1.end+1s"`
- Возможна и такая форма записи - `begin="anTrain.end-7.5s"`,что означает
  запуск другой анимации за 7.5 сек. до окончания анимации `с ID` -
  `anTrain`

*Используя эти возможности можно очень гибко согласовывать взаимодействие отдельных фрагментов анимации и в дальнейшем, что-то изменить, подстроить, не составит большого труда.*

**Ниже полный код всей анимации**

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.play-audio {

position:absolute;
top:0%;
left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1"   viewBox="0 0 800 540"  >
  <defs>
   <path id="walk"
   d="m343 268 34-10 50-9-33-86 22-14 7-21 8-3 13 18 34-25 47 65 22-19"  />
  <g id="Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1,-1)">
    <path   fill="none">
         <animate
          attributeName="d"
          begin="0.1s"
          dur="0.3s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          values="M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M 0,0 0,10 0,0 M0,10 0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0"/>
    </path> 
      </g>
  </defs>
  
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPdWW.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <path id="train" stroke-dasharray="312" stroke-dashoffset="312" stroke-width="2" d="M443 534 426 477 415 435 397 391 375 347 350 304 334 277 317 251" style="fill:none;stroke:violet;"/>
  
    <text
      font-size="28"
      font-family="Times New Roman"
      fill="#517DA6" >
<textPath id="result"
xlink:href="#train">
<tspan dx="0" > &#128645; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">  &#45; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">   &#45;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-15">   &#128643; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">   &#45; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">   &#45;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-15">   &#128643; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">   &#45; </tspan>
<tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-12">   &#45;</tspan>
<tspan dx="-15" >   &#128642; </tspan>
 <animate id="anTrain"
   begin="0s;an5.end"
   dur="12s"
   repeatCount="1"
   attributeName="startOffset"
   values="-60%;45%;45%;-60%"
   fill="freeze"/> 
</textPath>
</text>  
  
  <path id="walk"
   stroke-dasharray="409"
   stroke-dashoffset="409"
   stroke-width="3"
   d="m343 268 34-10 50-9-33-86 22-14 7-21 8-3 13 18 34-25 47 65 22-19"
   style="fill:none;stroke:#B34EE9">
  <animate id="anPathWalk"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   begin="anTrain.end-7.5s"
   dur="2s"
   values="409;0"
   fill="freeze" />
  </path>
  

 
 <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1.2)" style="stroke:blue; fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an2"
       begin="anPathWalk.end"
       dur="16s"
       repeatCount="1"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#walk"/>
     </animateMotion>    

          </use>    

      <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1.2)" style="stroke:crimson;" > 
     <animateMotion id="an3"
       begin="anPathWalk.end+0.5s"
       dur="17s" repeatCount="1"  >
             <mpath xlink:href="#walk"/>
      </animateMotion>   
     </use> 
       <use xlink:href="#Man"
       transform="translate(0,0)
       scale(1)"
       style="stroke:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an4"
       begin="anPathWalk.end+1s"
       dur="13s"
       repeatCount="1"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#walk"/>
      </animateMotion>   
       </use>      
       
       <use xlink:href="#Man"
       transform="translate(0,0)
       scale(0.8)"
       style="stroke:red;
       fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an5"
       begin="anPathWalk.end+1.5s"
       dur="11s"
       repeatCount="1"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#walk"/>
     </animateMotion>    
       </use>    
        <use xlink:href="#Man"
        transform="translate(0,0)
        scale(0.8)"
        style="stroke:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an5"
      begin="anPathWalk.end+1.8s"
      dur="9.5s" repeatCount="1"  >
         <mpath xlink:href="#walk"/>
     </animateMotion>    
       </use>   
  
</svg>

</div>
<div class="play-audio">    
        <audio class="my_audio" controls preload="true" autoplay="autoplay">
            <source src="https://w1.musify.club/track/dl/4064186/eruption-one-way-ticket-original.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
<div>
```

Приложение адаптивно и работает во всех современных браузерах, кроме `IE`

### Update 03.11.2020 г.

Добавлен аудиоплейер.

Использован трек: `eruption-one-way-ticket`

Comment: круто :) мне оч понравилось